# What's the relationship between Number and Function.prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes, prototype-chain

I'm reading the book *Javascript: the Good Parts*. I'm a little confused when I read the code below:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Number.method('integer',function(){
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

I think the first part of code above means that any function in JavaScript now has a method called *method*. But is "Number" also a function? Why does `Number.method` make sense ?

I suppose that Number inherits Number.prototype which inherits Object.prototype(Number->Number.prototype->Object.prototype), since Number has no "method" method at the beginning, it will look for it along the prototype chain. But Function.prototype isn't on the chain, right?

What's the relationship among Number, Number.prototype and Function.prototype?

---

**UPDATE I:**

I've searched for some extra information and am more confused now. Some say that Number is in fact a function and this seems to make sense because the value of `Number instanceof Function` is `true`.But the value of `(-10 / 3) instanceof Number` is `false`. Isn't this confusing? If a number in math (such as 3, 2.5, (-10 / 3)) is not even a `Number` in JavaScript, how can `(-10 / 3)` invoke `integer()` which is a method from `Number`? (The line below comes from the same book)

```
 document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer());
```

---

**UPDATE II:**

***Problem solved, basically.***

Thanks to @Xophmeister's help, now my conclusion is that `Number` can invoke `method` because `Number` is a constructor so that it is linked to `Function.prototype`. As for why a number(3, 2.5, (-10 / 3)) whose type is primitive type in JavaScript can invoke a method that object `Number` has, one should refer to [this page](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/).

I got this conclusion basically from @Xophmeister's help and a little search so it may not be precise enough. Any correction or completion is welcomed.

Comment: (-10 / 3) is a number but not a Number.

Comment: @simon But method `integer()` is defined in `Number`, right? If (-10 / 3) is not a `Number`, why can it invoke `integer()`?

Comment: `-10/3` is not a `Number` *object*, but has *type* `number`. I think sections 8.6.2 and 9.9 of the ECMA262 spec are relevant to this; particularly, the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` and `ToObject` internals of JS. This blog post might explain things better: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the prototype chain is: `Object` > `Function` > `Number`:

```
Number instanceof Function; // true
Number instanceof Object;   // true
Function instanceof Object; // true
```

Comment: `Object instanceof Function` returns `true`, too.

Comment: This, I presume, is because functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript.

Comment: Like what @neustroev.ai says, `Object instanceof Function` is `true`. Does that mean everything object in JavaScript is a Function?

Comment: It's because `Object` is a constructor and constructors in JS are always `Function`s. It's not true that everything is a `Function`: for example, if `a = {}` -- a "plain" object -- `a instanceof Function` is false, but `a instanceof Object` is true.

Comment: ...As such, I believe `Number instanceof Function` is true because `Number` is also a constructor, rather than it being the child of `Function`.

Comment: @Xophmeister I think your explanation makes sense, I'll give it a second thought...